# Iterating Ansible setup command

Tags: linux, bash, ansible

I want to use `ansible setup` module to retrieve hosts specs and I tried with  a bash for loop.

*Ansible version: 2.4*

My hosts inventory has been defined in a group of machines which I called *rhelmachines*

I would like to collect the following list of variables called "specs"

```
declare -a specs=("ansible_all_ipv4_addresses" "ansible_processor" "ansible_processor_cores" "ansible_uptime_seconds")
```

I am then trying to include the ansible command in a for bash loop:

```
for i in "${specs[@]}"
do
    ansible rhelmachines -m setup -a 'filter='$i'
done
```

how can I concatenate multiple filters in one connection only ?

Thanks!

Comment: So do you want your final command line to be `ansible rhelmachines -m setup -a filter=foo -a filter=bar` if the array contains `foo` and `bar`? Or `-a "foo,bar"`? Or something else? Please be explicit about *how* they should be concatenated.

Comment: BTW, your original code won't run at all -- the quotes aren't balanced. Maybe you wanted `-a "filter=$i"`?

Comment: I would like to avoid the need of a loop. So, yes, multiple filters in one line.

Comment: In one line *how*? `-a` just once, with commas or spaces in the argument that follows separating the list of specs? One `-a` per spec? Something else? Showing an actual example of the command line you want to generate would allow an answer (written by someone who doesn't know what format ansible wants for its `filter=` argument when passing multiple specs) to be something other than guesswork.

Comment: The desiderable output is 
ansible rhelmachines -m setup \
  -a ansible_all_ipv4_addresses \
  -a ansible_processor \
  -a ansible_processor_cores \
  -a ansible_uptime_seconds

as Charles proposed, but it appears Ansible does not support multiple filters in the same setup command at the moment :-(

Comment: BTW, it's pretty easy to just use `jq` to extract all five outputs you want from a single ansible run's JSON output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As one of the possible solution, I implemented an Ansible code exploiting Ansible **facts**. I implemented it first gathering the ansible facts. Then, I used a *local_action* and a loop. The loop indices are the several ansible facts. For every fact I am writing out a line of a file. In this way I am getting a file composed by all the ansible facts I declared in the loop for the *rhelmachines*.

```
---
- hosts: rhelmachines
  gather_facts: True
  tasks:
  - name: Gather Facts
    setup:
        gather_subset=all
    register: facts

  - debug:
      msg: "{{ facts.ansible_facts.ansible_all_ipv4_addresses }}"

  - name: copy content from facts to output file
    local_action:
     module: lineinfile
     line: "{{ item }}"
     path: /tmp/assessments/facts.txt
    loop:
      - "{{ facts.ansible_facts.ansible_all_ipv4_addresses }}"
      - "{{ facts.ansible_facts.ansible_all_ipv6_addresses }}"
```

Comment: it's ok but if you have more than one host in inventory and several facts are same they are omitted.

Comment: and content is mixed

Answer (score 0):

With a little `sed` hackery to convert `ansible`'s output to JSON, you can use `jq` to extract only the pieces you need:

```
ansible -m setup localhost | sed -e 's/^[[:alpha:]].*[|].* [>][>] {$/{/' | jq -n '
[inputs |
 .ansible_facts as $facts |
 $facts.ansible_hostname as $hostname |
 {($hostname): {
    "ipv4_addresses":  $facts.ansible_all_ipv4_addresses,
    "processor": $facts.ansible_processor[0],
    "cores": $facts.ansible_processor_cores,
    "uptime": $facts.ansible_uptime_seconds}}] | add'
```

...generates output of the form:

```
{
  "my-current-hostname": {
    "ipv4_addresses": [
      "192.168.119.129"
    ],
    "processor": "Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-6700HQ CPU @ 2.60GHz",
    "cores": 1,
    "uptime": null
  }
}
```

(run with ansible 1.4.5, which doesn't generate uptime).

Answer (score 0):

I took @Luigi Sambolino answer and make it better. His answer was failing on more than one host in the inventory. He proposed using `lineinfile` which has one con in this situation - every fact that was the same as other machines were omitted. Other drawback was that results wasn't sorted together, all was mixed.

I needed to take some basic information about systems, like IP, OS version, and so on. Here's my playbook:

```
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: true
  ignore_unreachable: true
  tasks:
  - name: get the facts
    setup:
      gather_subset=all
    register: facts
  - name: remove file
    local_action:
      module: file
      path: results
      state: absent
  - name: save results in file
    local_action:
      module: shell
      cmd: echo "{{ item }}" >> results
    with_together:
      - "{{ facts.ansible_facts.ansible_default_ipv4.address }}"
      - "{{ facts.ansible_facts.ansible_architecture }}"
      - "{{ facts.ansible_facts.ansible_distribution }}"
      - "{{ facts.ansible_facts.ansible_distribution_version }}"
      - "{{ facts.ansible_facts.ansible_hostname }}"
      - "{{ facts.ansible_facts.ansible_kernel }}"
```

Now the results look like this:

```
...
['10.200.1.21', 'x86_64', 'Ubuntu', '18.04', 'bacula', '4.15.18-7-pve']
['10.200.2.53', 'x86_64', 'Ubuntu', '18.04', 'webserver', '4.15.18-27-pve']
...
```

Square brackets can be deleted by `sed` and we have a nice CSV file that can be used with any spreadsheet, for example.

Answer (score -1):

```
specs=( "ansible_all_ipv4_addresses"
        "ansible_processor"
        "ansible_processor_cores"
        "ansible_uptime_seconds" )
args=( )
for spec in "${specs[@]}"; do args+=( -a "$spec" ); done
ansible rhelmachines -m setup "${args[@]}"
```

...will result in your final command being equivalent to:

```
ansible rhelmachines -m setup \
  -a ansible_all_ipv4_addresses \
  -a ansible_processor \
  -a ansible_processor_cores \
  -a ansible_uptime_seconds
```

Comment: Can't try this at the moment. If it works, this is the solution :-)

Comment: Doesn't work that way to me. In fact, the error is:
ERROR! this task 'setup' has extra params, which is only allowed in the following modules: command, win_command, shell, win_shell, script, include, include_vars, include_tasks, include_role, import_tasks, import_role, add_host, group_by, set_fact, raw, meta

Comment: If you run `set -x` first, what does the log *say* the code is running?

Comment: See this running at https://ideone.com/Np3Y5O. (There *was* a thinko that needed fixing, but as a simple variable name mismatch, hopefully it was obvious-to-the-reader).

Comment: I have no doubts about the script. What I am trying to say is that the ansible setup commands does not support multiple filters :-)

Comment: Sure. I answered this a question about using arrays to build argument lists in bash, not as a question about ansible -- which is why my comments on the question were encouraging you to clarify the details of the ansible command you wanted bash to generate.